# How to catch run-time errors with Literal used with Pydantic model

Tags: python, python-typing, pydantic

I have the following python types:

```
from typing import Literal
from pydantic import BaseModel, ConfigDict, ValidationError, NonNegativeFloat

Fruit= Literal['Apple','Banana','Kiwi','Orange']

class Recipe(BaseModel):
    model_config = ConfigDict(frozen=True)
    fruit: Fruit
```

This all works as expected but trying to use `Fruit` on its own elsewhere does not catch runtime issues. For instance, if I have the function:

```
def show_fruit(fruit: Fruit):
    print(fruit)

show_fruit('carrot')
```

The static type checker works but at run-time it doesn't throw any validation errors. I guess because `Literal` provides no run-time checking, but then how can i incorporate the two?

Comment: I have no experience using Pydantic, but have you tried to use [`@validate_call`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/validation_decorator/)? (named `validate_arguments` in Pydantic V1)

Comment: @mkrieger1 Oh very cool. Yes that does seem to solve the problem. Sucks I need to pepper that decorator everywhere but seems like a reasonable solution.

Comment: If you can already statically check it there is no point in using the decorator. Validation is mainly used for the boundary of the program where you receive user inputs which you have no control over and cannot statically check.

Answer (score 0):

For the model to be validated, you actually need to instantiate it. You're not instantiating a `Recipe` (the Pydantic model) in your code snippet. Try this:

```py
print(Recipe(fruit='carrot'))
```

The static type checker will complain about the type of the `fruit` keyword argument, and the code will also throw a validation error.